# How to configure Azure Mobile Service to populate custom dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have been doing quite a bit of research into Azure's various offerings and what they can do, however, it is quite hard to figure out how they might fit together. I have set up a Mobile Service to act as my mobile app's back-end, managing push notifications and data storage etc. This populates a SQL database I have provisioned, all good so far. However, I would now like to display this data in a dashboard type web app. Do I create a private API and host it on another Azure App Service and call it from a separate web app which populates a dashboard, or populate the dashboard directly by querying the SQL database? Not sure of the security implications of either set up, or implementation issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here is probably to create an empty Web App Service (Website) and have the Mobile Service populate the data on this website, in order to visualize it.

So keep the Mobile Service you have now, and connect it to a new website.

Comment: Thank you, so does this mean using the same SQL db and referencing it in the web app?

Comment: Yes, correct. Leave your SQL db as it, and have your newly created website connect to that!

Answer (score 2):

Azure App Service can combine both mobile and web components.  You didn't mention the preferred language, but ASP.NET (MVC5) and Node.js are supported for the mobile component.

If you have not started using the Mobile Service in production, add the Mobile Apps SDK to your website, update the client SDK to point to the Mobile Apps SDK and just have one site.

Refs for the Server SDKs:
* [node](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/)
* [ASP.NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/)